# Check for Numeric Value using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, numeric

How can I know if a VARCHAR field's value can be successfully converted to an integer?

I want to do it massively to insert records from one table to another...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IsNumeric() function returns 1 for strings (varchars) which can be converted to a number and 0 for those that cannot..

Check out [IsNumeric function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One issue whit IsNumeric() function is that You will get True and if number got decimal separator,
What is totally right, But if someone as I need to check straight to numbers in varchar, without decimal symbols, (I got that when I needed to calculate CHECK digit on barcode) You can use castom 
made function like

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[checkbarkod] 
(
    @ean_kod varchar(13)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
begin
    declare @duzina int
    declare @slovo char(1)
    declare @pozicija int
    declare @uredu bit
    set @duzina=len(@ean_kod) 
    while @duzina>0
        begin
            set @slovo=(substring(@ean_kod,@duzina,1))
            if  (@slovo not in('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'))
                begin
                    set @uredu=convert(bit,0)
                    break
                end
            else 
                begin
                    set @uredu=convert(bit,1)
                    set @duzina=@duzina-1
            end
        end
    RETURN @uredu
end
```